# How to find the record that violate unique key constraint?

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume I have two tables as follows,

Table A

```
    +-------+-------+-------+-------+
    | col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d |
    +-------+-------+-------+-------+
    |       |       |       |       |
    +-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Table B

```
    +-------+-------+-------+-------+
    | col_a | col_b | col_c | col_d |
    +-------+-------+-------+-------+
    |       |       |       |       |
    +-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I'm going to update Table A using Table B. Here are the conditions

1. records that are equal by `col_a` should update in Table A
2. records are not equal by `col_a` should inserted to Table A
3. Table A has a unique key constraint as (col_b,col_c,col_d)

Problem is when updating data in Table A, this unique key constraint fails for some records. 
Question is how can I identify records that violate unique key constraint using a query. (I don't have access to logs)

Comment: Would help if you posted the query that is failing

Comment: Well you can search for records that have the (col_b, col_c, col_d) group that you're inserting, right? That would tell you the record that already exists.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @Mark ,I'm using Oracle.

Comment: @Frisbee, it is part of a long stored procedure, therefore difficult to post it here.

Comment: @ McAdam331, this may happen while updating as well. By grouping records that are inserting may or may not cause the violation.

Comment: Then why did you tag it with Oracle and MySQL?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't have a unique key on `col_b, col_c, col_d` of `table_b`, this will result in a violation when copying over. You can identify problematic rows with a query like this:

```
SELECT col_b, col_c, col_d
  FROM table_b
  GROUP BY col_b, col_c, col_d
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

A similar query can be run on `table_a` joined to `table_b`, but the specific queries to run will depend on which columns will be updated in `table_a`.  For the insert case, a useful technique might be to use a `MINUS` between `table_a` and the proposed inserted row.

Comment: In the event that the a set of values for b, c, and d both exist in tables A and B, but those records have different values for column a, would it make sense to include table A into your count > 1 query? Otherwise, there could be a record in table B that is unique, but still violate the constraint when the OP goes to insert it.

Comment: @Ellesedil: yes, but to make the proper query we need to know which columns in `table_a` are to be updated. That is why I left it at a "similar" query. @Frisbee: one part of the question was inserting from one table to another. I consider that copying from one table to another. That was one part that could be partially addressed without further info.

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand your need, maybe something like this can find the rows that will give problems:

```
select *
from table_a a
inner join table_b b 
on (a.col_b  = b.col_b and
    a.col_c  = b.col_c and
    a.col_d  = b.col_d and
    a.col_a != b.col_a
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

I just identified the violator of unique constraint with the following steps (which I think are pretty straightforward):

1. Drop the constraint/unique index on Table A
2. Run your query to update/insert/merge into Table A
3. Run

   ```
   select col_b, col_c, col_d, count(*)
   from Table A
   group by col_b, col_c, col_d
   having count(*) > 1
   ```
4. The query results show your culprit(s)
5. Fix data/query
6. Recreate the constraint/unique index on Table A
7. Rerun query and it should work (fingers crossed)

Answer (score 0):

USE Merge Statement 
Update when matched on Cols b,c,d
and Insert when not matched.

A single Merge statement would take care of your problem Ex.

```
            MERGE INTO A a
            USING B b
            ON (a.colb = b.colb and a.colc=b.colc and so on..)
            WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET a.cola= b.cola
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (collist)
            VALUES (b.cols);
```

Comment: On the insert side: if table "b" has duplicates, inserting them both into "a" would throw an exception. On the update side: if it matches on "a" but modifies "b", "c", or "d" in such a way as to introduce a duplicate in "a", this would also not work. So this merge probably will not help the op identify the duplicates.

Comment: He can use log_error into clause and process failures later , just a thought.